# Devise sign in not completing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a normal Devise install with my Users model.  The sign up and sign out work fine but the sign in form simply redirects back to the sign in page.

I've kept almost everything default:

**session/new.html.erb**

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>

    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_session_path) do |f| %>
      <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email %></div><br/>

      <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password %></div><br/>

      <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
        <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
      <% end -%>

      <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
    <% end %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json



  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  # GET /users/new.json
  def new
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])


    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if params[:user][:password].blank?
      params[:user].delete(:password)
      params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

**routes**

```
 devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}

 resources :users
```

Here are the logs created after attempting to sign in.

```
Started POST "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-13 19:18:34 -0600
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"oPVQIraxxQ3m8I4hbqy0r/BLIUaESkNDLFhvtoRIf2Q=", "user"=>{"email"=>"MYEMAIL@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"oPVQIraxxQ3m8I4hbqy0r/BLIUaESkNDLFhvtoRIf2Q=", "user"=>{"email"=>"MYEMAIL@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  Rendered devise/_links.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 108ms (Views: 29.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

I tried adding changing the `form_for` to the following:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

but that sends me to `http://localhost:3000/users/login.user` which gives me this in the development logs:

```
Started POST "/users/login.user" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-13 19:21:36 -0600
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as 
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"oPVQIraxxQ3m8I4hbqy0r/BLIUaESkNDLFhvtoRIf2Q=", "user"=>{"email"=>"demeuseja@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

I'm sure it's a mistype or something that I'm overlooking since everything works besides the sign in, but I've been tinkering with it for hours and have no idea what the problem is.  Any point in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's my Users model as well:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  attr_accessible :bio, :employer, :looking, :name, :password, :statement, :user_id, :username



  validates :name, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 3 }

  has_many :venues

  scope :employer, where(employer:true)
  scope :looking, where(looking:true)
  scope :recent, order("created_at_desc").limit(3)


end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in order to temporarily fix this, I changed the the form in `sessions/new.html.erb` from the default:

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_session_path) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div><br/>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div><br/>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
  <% end -%>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>
```

to the following:

```
<%= form_tag new_user_session_path do %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'user[email]' %>
    <%= password_field_tag 'user[password]' %>
    <%=  submit_tag 'Login' %>
<% end %>
```

Now the sign in works fine, as well as the sign up and sign out.  I'm sure I'll have to go back and fix the real problem but at least now for testing purposes it works.  If someone posts an actual fix instead of a workaround like this I'll accept their answer instead.

Thanks for your other answers!

Comment: I added an edit to my original answer. Your post gave me an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's me, but I can't see what you've changed in the form_for from your first example, but the second request path is incorrect.

For your first example, it is correctly using the Devise::SessionController create action to sign the user in but it is returning a 401 unauthorized. The controller you provided is the UserController, which handles the create and update actions for creating a new user. It is not relevant here.

Try taking out the `resource_name` on the url so it looks like:

```
<%= form_for :resource, as: :resource_name, url: user_session_path do |f| %>
```

It is a 401 unauthorized error being returned so you might want to try resetting the user password to see if that solves it first.

**EDIT:**
Based on the answer you provided below, it gave me another idea. The devise examples might be a bit dated, especially if you're doing anything slightly off with the sign-in form (although, it doesn't look like it). You could throw these in your `application_helper` which will ensure that the resource definitions are set. You can see documentation about it [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app):

```
def resource_name
  :user
end

def resource
  @resource ||= User.new
end

def devise_mapping
   @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
end
```

Where `User.new` references your User model definition. Another idea is to strip out the resource stuff altogether, and just use your actual model names instead.

Comment: Ah sorry that was a typo.  I edited my question, but `<%= form_for :resource, as: :resource_name, url: user_session_path do |f| %>` is how I've had it, and it was adding the (resource_name) that gave me the login.user URL.  Thanks for looking at it though.

Comment: What do you mean it was adding it? Did you try resetting the password? Can you post your user model? You need to add `devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, :recoverable, :stretches => 20`

Comment: Wow I meant to say "*I* was adding the..."  It's not the password, I've tried making new users and signing in with each of them.  All of them sign up fine, sign out fine, but can't sign back in.  I edited my post with my user model.

Comment: I'm assuming you've run the devise:install and updated the database with the required columns?

Comment: I did yeah.  If you see the answer I posted I found a temporary fix that works for now.  +1 for your help though that was why I decided to try to change the form, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used a recent version of devise, but at a wild guess I'd say that:

```
path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}
```

means you should be using `login_path`  instead of `user_session_path`

---

Again a wild guess you may have already tried... but, in your user controller do you have a "skip before filter authenticate" or similar?

If so - the sign-in actions generally need to skip that before-filter, or it'll fail to get to the action itself because "you haven't signed in yet" while you're still attempting to sign in.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that as well as  `sign_in_path` and it gave me a `NoMethodError...undefined method `'login_path'`.

Comment: added another possibility... again a wild guess.